# React native view layer

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I'm trying to put a white dot over a green square like below.

[image: separate]

But no matter how I try I still get this. The background color and margin of the white dot is gone.

[image: overlay]

Here's the code.

```
<View style={backgroundColor: 'white', zIndex: 1, margin: 2, borderRadius: 10, borderWidth: 2} >   
  <View style={backgroundColor: 'green', zIndex: 0} />
</View>
```

I though zIndex will solve my problem but it doesn't. I've also tried swapping the order but it just give me a plain green square. Help?

```
<View style={backgroundColor: 'green', zIndex: 0}>
  <View style={backgroundColor: 'white', zIndex: 1, margin: 2, borderRadius: 10, borderWidth: 2} />   
</View>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need/want to use `z-index` for this. `z-index` is used for depth, to layer items that occupy the same space.

Read up on it here: [CSS Tricks - z-index](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/)

I'd agree that you want to make use of flexbox if you're trying to keep everything aligned.

Here's an example:

```js
<View style={styles.container}>

    <View style={styles.holder}>
      <View style={styles.circleHolder}>
            <View style={styles.circle} />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.square} />
    </View>

</View>
```

and the styling:

```js
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    circleHolder: {
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    circle: {
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        width: 150,
        height: 150,
        borderRadius: 75,
        borderWidth: 2
    },
    square: {
        backgroundColor: 'green',
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
    },
});
```

RNPlay: https://rnplay.org/apps/k5DbDQ

Comment: syles.holder is not available to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
<View>
  <View style={
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    zIndex: 1,
    margin: 2,
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderWidth: 2
  }/>
  <View style={backgroundColor: 'green', zIndex: 0}/>
</View>
```

Try this. You shouldn't be nesting them, because they are related to each other as a parent and child. By the way you might need to use flex to align them correctly :)